# Bug at merging Simple Responses from multiple webhook requests

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

When calling the webhook multiple times in one scene and sending simple responses there is a bug at merging the simple responses.

prompt from the first webhook call

```
{
    "override": false,
    "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "<speak><audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file1.mp3\"></speak>",
        "text": "Text 1"
    }
}
```

prompt from the second webhook call

```
{
    "override": false,
    "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "<speak><audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file2.mp3\"></audio> <audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file3.mp3\"></audio></speak>",
        "text": " Text 2"
    }
}
```

merged prompt in the response send to the user

```
{
    "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "<speak><speak><audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file1.mp3\"></speak> <audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file2.mp3\"/> <audio src=\"https://www.example.com/audio/file3.mp3\"/></speak>",
        "text": "Text 1 Text2"
    }
}
```

So with the two `speak` tags the SSML is invalide and is not spoken out.
Sometimes the speech object is completely missing.

I already created an Github [issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs/issues/5) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found out that the merging Bug is related to invalid SSML. Unfortunately there is no error message from Google for SSML errors.

And as a workaround for the problem that the speech object is completely missing I changed `conv.add(new Simple('Text'))` to `conv.prompt.firstSimple = new Simple('Text')` or `conv.prompt.lastSimple = new Simple('Text')`.